# how to Add 3 listboxes items into one listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm using vb.net form.

I have 3 listboxes each one contains many items (listbox1 , listbox2,listbox3)
and another empty listbox (listbox4)
im trying to add first three listboxes items into the 4th listbox

ex: ) listbox1 first items is 'A' , listbox2 first items is 'b' , listbox3 first items is 'c'
now listbox4 first item must be "Abc"

The problem is I't's work but keep loop the items.
here is my code :

```
For i = 1 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

       For j = i To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1

           For k = j To ListBox3.Items.Count - 1

               ListBox4.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items(j).ToString + ListBox2.Items(j).ToString + ListBox3.Items(k).ToString)

               Exit For
           Next
       Next
   Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested the loops. This means that the inner loops are repeated at each loop of the outer loops. E.g. If the three list boxes have 3, 4, and 6 elements the most inner loop will loop 3 x 4 x 6 = 72 times!

Instead make only one loop:

```
Dim n As Integer = _
    Math.Min(ListBox1.Items.Count, Math.Min(ListBox2.Items.Count, ListBox3.Items.Count))

For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
    ListBox4.Items.Add( _
        ListBox1.Items(i).ToString + _
        ListBox2.Items(i).ToString + _
        ListBox3.Items(i).ToString)
Next
```

Comment: Sir may i ask you if i want to add more than 3 listbox into 1 listbox , for example 5 or 6 listboxes into 1 listbox ? Many thanks @Oliver Jacot-descombes

Comment: I do not quite understand where the problem lies. It seems quite obvious and straight forward how to expand the example for more listboxes. If you know that the listboxes have all the same item count, you don't need the part with `Math.Min`. This just takes the minimum count of all listboxes in case they have different counts.  Instead just take the count from one of the listboxes: `Dim n As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count`.